# SVN is referring to my old class which i deleted already

Tags: svn, merge, trunk

Last night I updated from a trunk and merged 3 files and there was some error(s) (not compile time) while merging that I couldn't figure out. Before I figure out the problem I committed my changes which contained the merged files with others.

The automatic testing server sends me a build error that it couldn't find one of the class. I deleted that class locally and created with a new one with different name and replaced its usages. Then I updated from the trunk again and committed my changes but still the build error from the testing server is referring to the old class I deleted which no longer exists in my local machine and of course I committed those changes.

How should I fix this problem?

Comment: have you committed the package from where you have deleted the file? (basically have you committed the deletion to SVN server?)

Comment: Yeah. I committed the deletion to the SVN

Comment: When you do a "svn status ." or an "svn update .", do you see any indication that your working copy differs from the repository?

Comment: I did an update a min ago and since some developers committed other files, it didn't say there is no update. However, my files in which i was working are the same.

Comment: if you know revision, which was used for build, make build-test (part of) by hand - export or checkout into **fresh location** only needed **revision from repo** - this way you remove interference with (possible) WC-artifacts

Comment: Here is one thing I found right now. I think the file is still on the trunk. I used the changes tab to navigate to the place where I submitted the files and when I right click the file the "open repository version" is enabled and shows me the content of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create new working copy - may be your `.svn` is (are) corrupted. Then try to build in this new WC. Can you build successfully? Than you build server has cached artifacts from previous build ( like object files, compiled java classes etc. ). If you failed to build - then fix an error and commit it =)